# Why .ToString, Or .STAsText() keeps returning geographies instead of strings

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr

The question underlines the specific issue, but here's some context.

I'm trying to get the closest distance to each point between a set of points and polygons in SQL. The points are just lat/long of course, and I'm having no trouble rendering them as geometries or geographies.

The polygons are having one of two issues; ogr2ogr will load them as geometries just fine:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs “EPSG:4326” -f “MSSQLSpatial” “MSSQL:server={server};database= 
{database};uid={uid};pwd={pwd}” “{filepath to polygons}”  -overwrite -progress -skipfailures
```

and they display normally. However if I try to load them as geographies as in

```
-lco GEOM_TYPE=GEOGRAPHY
```

they all upload as geographies that cover the full extent of the spatial reference, so just giant polygons with x1 y1 at (-180,90) and x2 y2 at (180,-90).

The funny thing is that when I try to convert the geometries, which look fine, over to geographies using something in this vein

```
geography::STGeomFromWKB(ogr_geometry.STAsBinary(), 4326);
```

They do the same thing, just convert to the world covering polygons, and when I try to dissect things by looking at

```
ogr_geometry.STAsBinary()
```

or

```
ogr_geometry.STAsText()
```

I just get the same world covering polygons. They don't even convert to text. So does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What is the connection between the title and the contents of the question? I do  not see anything about strings in the question.

Comment: The command STAsText, for instance, should return a string, not a geometry or geography.

Answer (score 3):

You might have to reorient polygons, see topic **Orientation of Spatial Data** in Microsoft reference to understand why it matters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/polygon?view=sql-server-ver16

With wrong loop orientation, the polygon describes everything on the globe except what you actually want to describe. Use ReorientObject method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/reorientobject-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I never would have thought of this, but it looks like you solved it. Thanks so much!

Comment: One additional note, I had some trouble with MultiPolygons, and furthermore Geometry.STGeometryType() and Geography.STGeometryType() were sometimes (not always) returning different results. So the solution was a case statement that found instances where either or both Geometry and Geography returned MultiPolygon.

I cannot speak to why sometimes the Geometry and the Geography returned different GeometryTypes.

Comment: Wrong loops orientation can lead to many problems. For simple polygons you can fix them using ReorientObject. In case of polygon with holes or multipolygon - the interactions of multiple mis-interpreted loops creates invalid geography and can lead to random behavior. So best of all is to fix such data before loading it to SQL Server. I usually check polygon's STArea - inverted ones would have huge area.